# template template syntax problems with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a problem with variadic template templates:

```
            template <typename T> class A { };
            template< template <typename> class T> class B { };
            template <template <typename> class T, typename parm> class C { typedef T<parm> type; };
            template <typename... types> class D { };
            template <template <typename...> class T, typename ... parms> class E { typedef T<parms...> type; };

            // How to pass list in list??
            template < template <typename...> class ...T, ???>
            class F
            {
            };
```

First, pass a type to the template, no problem:

```
            A<int> a; //ok
```

Now, I want to create an instance from B, but no way to pass the template template param:

```
            B<A> b; // ok, but no chance to submit <int> inside A!
```

So I have to extend the parameter list:

```
            C<A, int> c; // ok, this transport int as parm into A
```

Now I play with variadic templates in standard fashion:

```
            D<> d1; // ok
            D<int, float, double> d2;   //ok
```

Passing parameters into the variadic part is also strait forward:

```
            E<D> e1;    //ok
            E<D, double, float, int> e2; //ok
```

BUT: If I want to have a list of lists, I find no syntax which will me enable to pass
parameter lists to the list of types. What my intend is something like this. but also the above example shows that `B<A<int>> b;` is an error! So the following example couldn't work :-(

```
            F< D< int, float>, D< int>, D <float, float, float> > f;
```

My target is to unroll the list of lists via template specialization. Any hints?

**My solution after I understood the problem. Thanks!**

Now I can unroll my variadic variadic template template as in the following example. The simple problem was, that I wait for a template class and not for a simple type. Sometimes, the solution can be so easy :-)

Thats my working result now:

```
    template <typename ... > class D;

    template <typename Head, typename... types>
    class D<Head, types...>
    {
       public:
          static void Do() { cout << "AnyType" << endl; D<types...>::Do(); }
    };

    template<>
    class D<>
    {
       public:
          static void Do() { cout << "End of D" << endl; }
    };

    template < typename ...T> class H;

    template < typename Head, typename ...T>
    class H<Head, T...>
    {
       public:
          static void Do()
          {
             cout << "unroll H" << endl;
             cout << "Subtype " << endl;
             Head::Do();
             H<T...>::Do();
          }
    };

    template <>
    class H<>
    {
       public:
          static void Do() { cout << "End of H" << endl; }
    };


    int main()
    {
       H< D<int,int,int>, D<float, double, int> >::Do();
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack one variadic specialisation at a time through specialisation:

```
template<typename...> struct S;
template<> struct S<> { constexpr static int n = 0; };
template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Us, typename... Vs>
struct S<T<Us...>, Vs...> {
    constexpr static int n = sizeof...(Us) + S<Vs...>::n;
};

template<typename...> struct D {};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << S<D<int, int, int>, D<int, int>, D<int>>::n << '\n'; // prints 6
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer open my eyes. I put my final solution to my question. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
template < template <typename...> class ...T >
class F
{
};
int main()
{
  F< D, D > f;
}
```

So, what F is expecting is a variadic template class, that takes another variadic template class as it's argument.

You can not expand the arguments of the arguments of the template class argument. If you specialize the template class that you pass as argument, then you'll get the specialized version.

This :

```
 F< D< int, float>, D< int>, D <float, float, float> > f;
```

doesn't work, since F expects variadic template class, taking variadic template classes as types, and `D< int, float>` is not a template anymore (it is a concrete class).

Comment: What you describe is the same as my code in `B<A> b;`. My question is regarding to get list of lists, which means to have parameters which could be expanded. Is it really impossible to use list of lists? I wont believe :-)

Comment: @Klaus You wrote : `no chance to submit <int> inside A!`. You can do in A this `typedef A type` and use it in B as `typename A::type`, but you can not do that in a variadic template (this can not be done : `typedef typename... types`)

Comment: Seems to be that I am on the totally wrong way and variadic template templates are not the solution. Is there any other way to get the required functionality? It is easy to get ONE list which could be expanded via specialization. I am still in hope that there is also a way to such things also with a list of lists. Any hint is wellcome! Can you give me an working example of what you mean in your last comment?

Comment: @Klaus actually, the last part of the comment is rubbish. You need to know the type in B, because it's template parameter is a template class.